# Location of Java examples on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, jpda

I'm looking for the example source code that is supposed to come with the JVM, specifically the file demo/jpda/examples.jar.  Where is this located on OSX? (is it even on Mac OSX?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Evan points out Apple provides a proprietary implementation of the JVM and so it doesn't necessarily provide the same example.  However, if you download the OS X developer tools either from Apple or copy them off of the media that came with your computer, you can find a number of Java application source files and examples in /Macintosh HD/Developer/Extras/Java.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty sure there aren't any examples/samples on Mac OS X. This is because Apple provides its own version of Java.

http://developer.apple.com/java/faq/